# How I can send request to Web API controller from JavaScript with file and Object.?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my API Method and i want to send request from jQuery to this method.When I send request file does not found in the API.Kindly Help me if iam not on right path.

```
[Route("NewDocument/{ownerCode}"), HttpPost]
    public virtual dynamic NewDocument(Guid ownerCode, DocumentDto document)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
         {
            // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
            {
                document.Name = file.FileName;
                document.MimeType = file.ContentType;
                return base.NewDocument(ownerCode, file, document);
            }
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

My Script is here as :

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file","9780672337574.pdf");
form.append("document.Code", "edb208c4-7eef-4b8f-99eb-aa6e2c1417ea");
//all document will append here
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:15709/v1/items/NewDocument/edb208c4-7eef-4b8f-     99eb-aa6e2c1417ea",
   "method": "POST",
   "headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer Token",
    },
   "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    "data": form
   }
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: pretty sure you set `contentType` as `multipart/form-data`, not mimeType. Mime Type is related to the type of data within the file. Read the docs! http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . P.S. and don't use async:true unless you have a very good reason - it's terrible for user experience (it locks the browser)

Comment: and also, `form.append("file","9780672337574.pdf");` just appends the string "9780672337574.pdf" to your request, it doesn't attach the file. You have to get the info from the upload control in your UI.This looks like a good tutorial: https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax . N.B. this uses contentType: false as you have done, so it's worth trying with that value as well. But you certainly have to actually attach the file itself, not just an arbitrary string. You might have to adjust the data keys generated to match what your controller is expecting.